# Why will my fivereborn and discordjs code not send my embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fivem

My code will not send my embed.
I'm using fivereborn to get info from my fivem server and I want to make so every minute the bot will send a embed but if the server is closed it will show that the server is closed.

My code is here **:**

```
const { Collection, Client, Intents, Discord, Activity, TextChannel } = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const fivereborn = require('fivereborn-query');
const bot = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
})
const config = require('./config.json');
const { Channel } = require('diagnostics_channel');
const prefix = config.prefix
const token = config.token
bot.commands = new Collection();
bot.aliases = new Collection();
bot.categories = fs.readdirSync("./commands/");
["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(bot);
});
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} ✅`)
})
bot.on('message', async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd.length == 0 ) return;
    let command = bot.commands.get(cmd)
    if(!command) command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
    if(command) command.run(bot, message, args)
})
```

The `ip` port and server name variables is here **:**

```
const ip = config.serverIp
const port = config.serverPort
const sName = config.serverName
var MoonRPEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
```

The code that sends the status embeds is here **:**

```
function status(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    fivereborn.query(ip, port, (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(data)

        bot.channels.fetch('941736918104821820').then(ch => {
          if (ch.isText()) {
            ch.bulkDelete(10);
          }

          makeOpenStatusEmbed(data.maxclients, data.clients);

        })

      } else {
        console.log('server closed')
        //console.log(err); // If a error is true then this will log that error and then stop it from going by
        bot.channels.fetch('941736918104821820').then(ch => {
          if (ch.isText()) {
            ch.bulkDelete(10);
          }

          makeClosedStatusEmbed();

        })
      }
    });

        status();
    }, 60000); // Waits 1 minute
}
status()
```

The embed the bot will send when the server is on is here **:**

````
async function makeOpenStatusEmbed(maxUsers, currentUsers) {
  var openStatusEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#ff0000')
  .setAuthor({ name: "Galaxy Network Status", icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703252325686575124/934779887112302652/Moonrp_logo-min.png' })
  .setDescription('')
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Server Åben', value: '```✅```', inline: true },
    { name: 'Spillere inde', value: '```'+currentUsers+'/'+maxUsers+'```', inline: true },
    { name: 'Server IP', value: '```cfx.re/join/ybrgv5```' }
    )
    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
    .setFooter({ text: 'Galaxy Bot', icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703252325686575124/934779887112302652/Moonrp_logo-min.png' });

    const sChannel = await bot.channels.fetch('941736918104821820')
    //console.log(sChannel)
    sChannel.send({ embeds: [openStatusEmbed] });
}
````

My embed the bot will send when the server is closed is here **:**

````
async function makeClosedStatusEmbed() {
  var closedStatusEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#ff0000')
  .setAuthor({ name: "Galaxy Network Status", icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703252325686575124/934779887112302652/Moonrp_logo-min.png' })
  .setDescription('')
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Server Åben', value: '```❌```', inline: true },
    { name: 'Spillere inde', value: '```0/48```', inline: true },
    { name: 'Server IP', value: '```cfx.re/join/ybrgv5```' }
    )
    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
    .setFooter({ text: 'Galaxy Bot', icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703252325686575124/934779887112302652/Moonrp_logo-min.png' });

    const sChannel = await bot.channels.fetch('941736918104821820')
    //console.log(sChannel)
    sChannel.send({ embeds: [closedStatusEmbed] });
  }

  bot.login(token).then(t => {
  });
````

`The discord.js version is 13.6.0`

`The fivereborn-query version is 1.0.4`

Comment: You'll need to add the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Where will i need to add the GUILD_MESSAGES?

Comment: Change `intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]` to `intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]`

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Ok but the bot will send the embed when the server is on but when the server is closed it will not send the message like before